# Kile on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, settings, kile

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 and I really like Kile to edit latex documents. I tried some other editors, but I really think Kile is the best one by far. However, one thing in Kile is very annoying. On my machine, any changes I make in settings, like checking "Dynamic Word Wrap" or checking "Automatic Spell Checking", does not persist. In other words, these changes are applied while I have Kile opened. After closing and opening Kile again, all these changes are lost and I have to reconfigure Kile. I googled about this issue, but could not find a solution. I changed the owner of the ~/.kde to my user and gave permission to anyone to read and write to ~/.kde/share/config/kilerc (the file where kile stores his configurations). However, he always starts with his default config, like if it was the first run. I don't know what to do more, any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you opened `~/.kde/share/config/kilerc` to see if it can be manually edited?

Comment: Hello Cornelius. Thanks for your reply. Yes, i opened kilerc and it can be manually edited. In fact, I am editing this file to make some changes, but it seems I can't change every settings in Kile through it (i.e. dictionaries and auto spell check) and I really think this is not the solution. There must be something that does not allow Kile to persist settings between sessions...

Comment: Make a backup copy of it, then delete it and let Kile create it again. Now customize Kile maybe it will save preferences.

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work. I am running out of ideas =(. Maybe I'll try to get the latest version right from their git (beta version), compile and try it. It's really bad to configure a lot of options + dictionary + spell checking every time.

Comment: Are you using the Settings -> Configure Kile menu or the context menu?

Comment: I was using both and none was working 3 months ago. Now, in the current version of Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (updated today), it seems that the changes you make using the Settings -> Configure Kile are persisted, but the changes using the context menu do not. But that's enough for me. Not persisting any changes in any way was the real problem.

Thanks for your help!!!